# How do you add a WMTS tile to Bokeh figure?

Tags: python, bokeh, figure, tile

How does one add a custom tile provider/source to a Bokeh figure using a tile provider such as this USGS source?:
https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Read the guideline on how to post questions. Be specific and show your personal efforts at solving th question. Do not rely on the community to solve issues without having attempted to do so on your own.

Answer (score 1):

OK... now that I've posted my first question, finally found the example on how to do this:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-2.3/examples/models/file/tile_source.py